# python float multiplication - simple math not outputting correctly

Tags: python

The value printed by my code below is

```
3.7275e-05
```

why did this simple math question not return 0.000037275?

(.00003550 * .05)= .000001775 + .00003550 = .0000372575

```
buyinamount = .00003550
percentgain = .05
amtgained=float(buyinamount*percentgain)+buyinamount
print amtgained
```

Comment: Are you asking why it printed `3.7275e-05` instead of `0000372575`?

Comment: Look at the value printed: you got exactly the value you expected, just not in the format you expressed.  Look up a tutorial on Python output formatting if you want to change the default.

Comment: yes. and i will thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a precision issue caused by how decimal number are stored in the memory. All numbers, integers and decimals, are stored in the form of binary (1s and 0s). Therefore, some decimals cannot be stored with 100% precision, thus messing the calculation too.

In python, you can use the `Fraction` and `Decimal` module to make your calculation more accurate (this is the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for that)

Comment: thanks I am a beginner trying to bang out some easy math! your answer has helped!

Comment: `x = .2 + .1`    
`x`     
`0.30000000000000004`
you'll have to just round it. This is common to all programming languages (except in R) which is a statistical language.  Andreas nailed it!